# In an array of Objects, how do I return all Objects by property in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I want to do is create a multi-checkbox filter. So when I click the checkbox titled 'Accessories', it returns all items that contain the value 'Accessories' under the property 'type'.
But before I do that I need to understand how to manipulate and traverse my data properly.

I have a json file named *products* that contains all of the products of a store and it looks like so.

```
[
  {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Net and Post Set",
  "type" : "Accessories",
  "price" : 35,
  "desc" : "It's a solid blade. 11111"
},{
  "id" : 10,
  "name" : "Platinum 3* Balls (Bag of 36)",
  "type" : "Balls",
  "price" : 12,
  "desc" : "It's a solid blade. 11111"
},{
  "id" : 22,
  "name" : "Galaxy MC2",
  "type" : "Blades",
  "category" : "Composite",
  "price" : 60,
  "desc" : "It's a solid blade. 11111"
},
{
  "id" : 23,
  "name" : "Oversized Carbon fl, st",
  "type" : "Blades",
  "category" : "Composite",
  "price" : 32,
  "desc" : "It's a solid blade. 11111"
}
]
```

But when i print it out in the console it is a [mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMtqe.png).
Firstly, it prints as an array within an array. Secondly, that nested array has the key '0' and the rest of the values also have keys.

Lets assume im passing *products.json* to a function. In order to print the array without the leading zero to the console I have to call `console.log(props.products[0])`.

But my question is how do I reference the `"type"` property of all of the Objects in `props.products[0]`. `props.products[0].type` returns undefined. Which means I would have to step through each and every item?

Comment: Please do not downvote this question without explaining why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` with destructuring.

```js
const props = {
  products: [
    [{ "id": 1, "name": "Net and Post Set", "type": "Accessories", "price": 35, "desc": "It's a solid blade. 11111" }, { "id": 10, "name": "Platinum 3* Balls (Bag of 36)", "type": "Balls", "price": 12, "desc": "It's a solid blade. 11111" }, { "id": 22, "name": "Galaxy MC2", "type": "Blades", "category": "Composite", "price": 60, "desc": "It's a solid blade. 11111" }, { "id": 23, "name": "Oversized Carbon fl, st", "type": "Blades", "category": "Composite", "price": 32, "desc": "It's a solid blade. 11111" } ]
  ]
};
const types = props.products[0].map(({type})=>type);
console.log(types);
```